# High-Low Paraproduct Convergence in $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

For $f, g \in \mathcal{S}$, define $f_k = P_k f$, $g^k = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{k-3}P_j g$, where $P_j$ is the Littlewood-Paley projection. Is it true that

$$
  P(f, g) = \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty f_j g^j
$$

converges in $L^p$ and satisfies the Holder type inequality

$$
\|P(f, g)\|_{L^p} \le C \|f\|_{L^q}\|g\|_{L^r}
$$

for $\dfrac{1}{p} = \dfrac{1}{q} + \dfrac{1}{r}$ ? Why?

Comment: I think this is true as long as $1 < p < \infty$. The rough idea is that $\| P(f,g) \|_{L^p}$ can be controlled by the $L^p$ norm of the square function $( \sum_j | f_j g^j |^2 )^{1/2}$, which can in turn be controlled pointwise by the product of the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $g$ times the Littlewood-Paley square function of $f$. See page 9 of notes here: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247b.1.07w/notes6.pdf